Cannot share Product2 records with Experience cloud users
I am in the process of creating an experience cloud site using the Build Your Own LWR template. I created a LWC component which has a lightning-record-picker component that displays records from the Product2 object. After publishing the site I get an error when the component is loaded which says as below. I am thinking this is a permission issue as I dont see this message while testing.

Here are my filter settings for the lightning-record-picker component-
    matchingInfo = {
        primaryField: { fieldPath: 'Name' },
        additionalFields: [{ fieldPath: 'Search_Field__c' }],
    };
    displayInfo = {
        additionalFields: ["Manufacturer__c"],
    };
    filter = {};
this.filter = {
            criteria: [
                {
                    fieldPath: 'Family',
                    operator: 'eq',
                    value: 'Parts',
                },
                {
                    fieldPath: 'Family',
                    operator: 'eq',
                    value: 'Tires & Batteries',
                },
                {
                    fieldPath: 'Type_of_Equipment__c',
                    operator: 'eq',
                    value: '',
                },
                {
                    fieldPath: 'Family',
                    operator: 'eq',
                    value: 'Rental',
                },
                {
                    fieldPath: 'Type_of_Equipment__c',
                    operator: 'eq',
                    value: this.veteranEquipmentType,
                },
            ],
            filterLogic: '(1 OR 2 AND 3) OR (4 AND 5)',

        };

What I am looking to have is the Product2 records be made available for community profile.  These are the few steps I tried -

Navigated to the community profile -> selected object settings -> provided read access to the fields of the Product2 object. This didn't help.
Navigated to Sharing settings and tried to create a sharing rule for the product2 object. Unfortunately here I dont see an option to share the records with the community profile but only  with the guest community profile. Below is the snip -


What am I missing here. This component works perfectly well in our salesforce org with the same filter.
Please advise!

What's the user license type - Customer Community or Partner Community?  Customer Community licenses do not have access to Opportunity and other Sales Cloud objects, so I imagine they can't access Product2 or related objs.

@DavidCheng Customer Community Plus

A long time ago there was a Salesforce document that clearly stated what objects were not visible to community users, but I can't find it now.  You should open a case with Salesforce.

@sumchans Compare the sharing settings of the orgs. Is your Product2 Object configured same settings for the OWD? And also look under Product settings to see if everything is same

@MohithShrivastava this has been solved. It was just the logging in not happening the right way. After the user logs in the isGuest property of the @salesforce/user/isGuest was always showing true, which was not right. Once that was fixed I was able to see records from the product object.

The issue here was with the logging process not happening the right way. The isGuest property of the @salesforce/user/module was always showing true even after a successful login.
